# How to get positive and negative voltage for my circuit from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: power, electronics

I am trying to connect a circuit which needs a +5 V and -5 V input. How can I get both voltages from a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Truth is, Raspberry Pi cannot generate -5V for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an EE question than a Pi question, but here goes.

There are many power supply circuits which can convert between +5V to +/- 5V. [A quick web search show a bunch of responses](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%2B5v%20in%20%2B%2F-%205v%20out&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (I used google with "+5V to +/- 5V")

[There is even an EE Stack Exchange question/answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3042/converting-scaling-a-voltage-range-0v-5v-to-5v-5v).

Comment: i tried searching before i asked but i guess i didn't choose the right words for google but thanks to you now i know the right search word 
Thanks alot